# Mapreduce : Capture all Job statistics

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is there a way I can capture all stats related to  Job? I need this info to print it in an email  (instead of logging into Job Tracker) to view it

Comment: I am looking for stats other than counters. Like memory on the data nodes when the job is running, CPU utilization % etc. Can i got those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.,

```
Job job = ...
...
boolean successful = job.waitForCompletion(true);
String stats = job.getCounters().toString();
```